# What is the facial feature extraction algorithm of picasa? 

Tags: picasa, face-recognition

I'm researching facial feature extraction algorithms. I have played with several face recognition solutions, but I prefer picasa.
I want to know the facial feature extraction algorithm of picasa.  Can you help me?  Please give me your helpful advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: They most likely don't want you to know..

Answer (score 4):

Google bought two companies working on face detection, [Neven Vision in 2006](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-neven-vision-image-recognition/3728/) and Pittsburgh Pattern Recognition or [PittPatt in 2011](http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/22/google-acquires-facial-recognition-software-company-pittpatt/). Neven Vision was most likely used for early versions of Picasa. Hard to say for sure.

Some more information about Neven Vision's algorithms can be found in [scholarly articles](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=neven+vision+algorithm&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=2OQsUKHxKIrpygGXi4GoAg&ved=0CGQQgQMwAA) and their [patent filings](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-neven-vision-image-recognition/3728/).

Comment: thanks for your attention.
i tried to find it at the where you offered.
but i can't find still.
how must i do?

Comment: I don't think they published the algorithm directly. You have to interpret the publicly available information like their patent filings to figure out what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try opencv it seems to have closer face detection...but u will have write your own face recognition algorithm...they have given a formula to do that check out opencv.com

Never use face recognition as means for any authentication.....because even android has a api for that and it has got bad review for image recognition.....likewise a picasa also employs face recognition but it's not that good...
Finally iphoto app apple has achieved it almost to 95 percent perfection...

The iPhoto algorithm is learning based algorithm if u let iphoto know wrong face recgnition images it will learn from that....

But neither iPhoto nor picasa has published this..

Check out the below URLs...
http://www.ratchetup.com/eyes/2009/02/comparing-iphoto-and-google-face-recognition.html

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2011/10/first-look-android-40-sdk-opens-up-face-recognition-apis/

http://blog.chron.com/techblog/2011/12/android-4-0s-facial-recognition-is-cool-but-dont-trust-it-yet/